# What is the time of sending/receiving a network packet comprised of?

Tags: speed, latency

When I do a **traceroute**, I can see the **round trip time** in milliseconds or "ms", for my packet(s) to reach that point and return to my computer.

[image]

Let the round trip time be the variable *x*. For the *x* ms that each round trip takes, how can one best split up that *x* ms, into smaller amounts of time, for the different variables and constants that go into the *x* ms?

For example, if a pack goes from my computer to another, my CPU/network card needs to process that instruction *p1*, send that to my router over Wifi *w1*, my router's CPU needs to process that request *r1*, then at the speed of *e* (constant) - *y* it travels over optic fiber to the next router *(e-y)1*, etc... Then the same path back: ... *(e-y)2*, *r2*, *w2*, *p2*

Now if *x* = *p1* + *w1* + *r1* + *(e-y)1* + *(e-y)2* + *r2* + *w2* + *p2* etc....

How to I determine what the composition of the round trip is, and the speed/latency of those specific components are? Is there a way to split those time of the packet traveling over wifi/wire/light at each destination, and the time of the processing in the hosts/network infrastructure at each point?

Comment: "_Is there a way to split those time of the packet traveling over wifi/wire/light at each destination, and the time of the processing in the hosts/network infrastructure at each point?_" No, and simply is not the purpose of traceroute. You use traceroute to see if the path of packets in your network matches what you expect it to be to aid in troubleshooting.

Comment: @RonMaupin The question in NOT about traceroute. Traceroute is just an example I used. I'm asking if there is ANY way of doing that. The question is NOT if traceroute specifically can do that.

Comment: Again, I answered, "No," to the question. For what you want to do, there are no readily available tools, and such a recommendation would be off-topic anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, No.  It might be possible to measure these components separately (for example, the propagation delay of fiber), but in practice delays can vary widely, depending on the other tasks the computer is doing, contention for the wireless channel, *etc*.

Also, the RTT is measured against your computer's system clock, which has its own inaccuracies.

Answer (score 1):

> When I do a traceroute, I can see the round trip time in milliseconds or "ms", for my packet(s) to reach that point and return to my computer.

Not quite true - what you see is the time between sending out an ICMP *echo request* probe and receiving an ICMP *time exceeded* reply from the L3 hop that the probe expires on.

The difference to the RTT with an actual transport protocol is that ICMP processing is usually of very low priority on network devices. The times you see can be seen as an upper bound for the actual RTT. You can see the discrepancy on hop 4 where the indicated RTT is higher than for hop 5 beyond that.

Each L3 hop that you see in `tracert` output delays each packet by its *nodal delay*. That delay consists of

- serialization or transmission delay (time to de/serialize the data)
- propagation delay (time for signal to cross distance)
- processing delay (interpretation, forwarding, queueing)

(Ordering of delays may vary from the current perspective. There's another serialization taking place when sending out a packet, but since it overlaps with reception on the next hop it can be neglected.)

Hidden between those L3 hops are intermediate L2 hops with the exact same delays each. `tracert` can't see those because it relies on the L3 TTL mechanism which isn't used by L2 nodes (switches, bridges).

Also hidden are any other forwarding hops that don't decrement the relevant packet TTL, e.g. when tunneling.